# Converting microequivalents per liter to mg for sodium?

Tags: human-biology, hematology, nutrition, units

I read that a normal blood sodium level is between 135 and 145 milliequivalents per liter (mEq/L). Hyponatremia occurs when the sodium in your blood falls below 135 mEq/L.

How do I convert mEq/L to a value in milligrams (mg) so I can understand how many mg of sodium should be normally be ingested into the body?

I understand the values is between 250-500 mg/day, but would like to see this correlated with the mEq/L units.

Comment: This is not a good way to determine "how many mg of sodium should be normally be ingested".

Comment: Is there no conversion of the units?  What is the preferred way?

Comment: It just has nothing to do with the goal you are wanting to achieve. If you borrow a car and want to replace the gas you used, it doesn't help you to know how much fits in the tank.

Comment: @BryanKrause I don't understand your reasoning and analogy.  Can you explain in terms of units, metric and science what you are trying to say?  mEq/L is a concentration of sodium per liter of blood.  1 mEq/L = 1 mmol/L, 1 mmol/L = 46 mg/L.  I'm confused because this suggests 135 mmol/L * 46 (mg/L)/(mmol/L) = 6,210 mg/L concentration of sodium.  If the body has 5L of blood, then 6,210 mg/L * 5L = 31,050 mg of sodium is well above the RDV of 2,300 mg.  Ideas?

Comment: You don't need to eat as much salt as you have in your body (e.g., size of gas tank). You need to eat as much salt as you *lose*: through urine/feces, sweat, etc.

Comment: Does this suggest, based on above math in comment, that the body keeps 31,050 mg of salt in it's system and perhaps loses 250-500 mg of salt per day (through sweat and urine)?  Therefore we need to ingest 250-500 mg of salt per day to keep up with the loss?